# What asterisk means before variable name in exists() function?

Tags: vimscript, variables

"filetype.vim" has line:

```
if exists("*fnameescape")
```

What '*' means here? Is it suppose to dereference any value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The star is used to check if a function exists. In this case [`fnameescape()`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#fnameescape%28%29).

See [`:help exists()`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#exists%28%29) for details of what other prefixes you can use.